# Where to specify jar file being used by OpenGTS to access SQL Server (sqljdbc4.jar)

Tags: java, sql-server

I'm running OpenGTS on a Windows 2012 server with Tomcat 7 and Java 1.7.  I'd like to use SQL Server as I already have this installed.  The specification was very clear on how to update the common.conf to point to the proper sql server database.  However, when I run checkinstall.bat, (or any other DB tool for OpenGTS) I get an exception:

```
 SEVERE: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.
     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.<init>(SQLServerConnection.java:304)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1011)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.opengts.dbtools.DBConnection.getConnection(DBConnection.java:659)
    at org.opengts.dbtools.DBConnection.createStatement(DBConnection.java:769)
    at org.opengts.dbtools.DBConnection._execute(DBConnection.java:856)
    at org.opengts.dbtools.DBConnection.execute(DBConnection.java:811)
    at org.opengts.dbtools.DBConnection.execute(DBConnection.java:793)
    at org.opengts.dbtools.DBFactory.tableExists(DBFactory.java:1648)
    at org.opengts.tools.CheckInstall.main(CheckInstall.java:2100)
```

I'm pretty sure I've REMOVED or RENAMED sqljdbc.jar (perhaps renaming is not enough) in folders containing included jar files.  I don't see any config file specifying this.  I'm not a Java developer usually, but I feel there should be a simple thing I can do to "use" the sqljdbc4.jar that I have.  I just don't know what that simple thing is...  Any help would be appreciated!

It would certainly help if the SEVERE warning above which says "this" driver is not supported by JRE 1.7 would be perhaps more specific and let me know what driver "this" is...

Answer (score 0):

Arg.  There are too many JRE's on this machine!  I found I had renamed the file in another JRE folder in lib\ext, so I removed that sqljdbc.jar file entirely.  Now it is gone.  Now the program works.